# Large database configuration

Tags: database, relational

What is the best way to optimize a database with millions of records and hundreds of simultaneous queries?

The database holds 2 significant tables, in a one to many relationship (table1 has a column for the key of table2).
Indexing has been applied for the relevant columns.
Caching is not very effective because each record is being read only few times after it has been inserted or updated, an not in a known time frame.
The data can be logically arranged to be distributed between different databases without the need for cross-database query.

What is the best database engine and configuration for this table structure?
Can something be done in other layers of the application?

Comment: "millions of rows" is not considered large these days. Any modern DBMS should be able to cope with that - especially if each row is retrieved through an index. Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Database tuning heavily depends on the DBMS.

Comment: Might get more help on this on serverfault?

Comment: The issue is that I need to support a large number of simultaneous queries and caching will not be effective. I am open for suggestions regarding the DBMS to use.